# Google invisible recaptcha stopped working in AU

Tags: recaptcha, invisible, magento-1.13

Starting from the 18th of June, the Recaptcha on our Magento M1 project has stopped working.
In recaptcha__en.js script function Array.prototype.filter returns an error this.each is not a function, because this is not an Array, it’s NodeList, and it can’t be filtered like this.

[image]

On the project side, we send a request to URL https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js, which returns different responses for different countries.

For AU IP (Also checked IE IP) request script src ashttps://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/FDTCuNjXhn1sV0lk31aK53uB/recaptcha__en.js

And for EU region it uses https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/6OAif-f8nYV0qSFmq-D6Qssr/recaptcha__en.js

Please advise how to solve the problem so we could re-enable the Recaptcha. Could you also tell what could cause it from stopping working?

Comment: You have to try view the console log, what was error

Answer (score 12):

Same here, the problem started today at the same time in magento 1, solved with this js :

```
if ('NodeList' in window) {
    if (!NodeList.prototype.each && NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
        NodeList.prototype.each = NodeList.prototype.forEach;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just added it right before where I call recaptcha's api.js and problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. I solved it by adding these lines of code just before you have the google ready function call. `grecaptcha.ready(...`

```
//fix google recaptcha
if ('NodeList' in window) {
    if (!NodeList.prototype.each && NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
        NodeList.prototype.each = NodeList.prototype.forEach;
    }
}
```

And the error has been removed.